# How I make two ts files for parent route and child route in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I was trying to develop an application with the help of Angular2 route. My project is simple.

Lets explain first. In Home page, I have 2 nav button. a. Home. b. Contact us.  So, 
1. I made a ts file name :- app.route.ts..
    Where I mentioned 2 path by

```
{
    path : 'myapps/contact', component : ContactComponent,
},
{
    path : 'myapps/home', component : HomeComponent
},
```

2. In app.component.ts section I used the following code,

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="myapps/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
  <a routerLink="myapps/contact" routerLinkActive="active">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Upto this my program is working perfectly. But after that, I added some features.. I segregate my Contact details into two parts. a. Mail Contact and b. Phone contact..

Problem had created here. When I am adding this two children of Contact into app.routing.ts then it is again started working. Like,

```
{
    path : 'myapps/contact', component : ContactComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'mail', pathMatch: 'full' },
         { path : 'mail', component : MailComponent },
        { path : 'phone', component : PhoneComponent },

      ]
},
```

But I want to make two separate file for this routing...

1. app.routing.ts where I will mention just mother routing like home, contacts and
2. contact.routing.ts where I want to mention child routing of contact like mail and phone.

How May I segregate this parts...?

Please suggest me anyone.. Thanks in advance for your attention.

Full Code is here.....

app.module.ts..

import { contactRouting } from '../../Components/Contacts/ContactsRouting/Contacts.routing';

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/myapps/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path : 'myapps/contact', component : ContactComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'mail', pathMatch: 'full' }
     ]
},
{
    path : 'myapps/home', component : HomeComponent
},
{
    path: '**',      component: PageNotFoundComponent
}
];
```

app.component.ts ....

template: `

## My Angular App

Home
         Contact

contact.routing.ts

```
{
    path : 'mail', component : MailComponent
},
{
    path : 'phone', component : PhoneComponent
}
];
```

Component.contact.ts

template:

```
    <nav>
          <a routerLink="mail" routerLinkActive="active">Mail</a>
          <a routerLink="phone" routerLinkActive="active">Phone</a>
     </nav>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a file `contact.routes.ts`

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MailComponent } from './Component.mail';
import { PhoneComponent } from './Component.phone';

export const contactRoutes : Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'mail', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path : 'mail', component : MailComponent },
    {path : 'phone', component : PhoneComponent  }
];
```

then now in your app.route.ts you need to do this

```
//keep everytning esle and add this following line
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './Component.home';
import { ContactComponent } from './Component.contact';

import { contactRoutes } from './Contacts.routing';

const appRoutes : Routes = [
     {
        path : '', component : HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'contact', component : ContactComponent,
        children: [

            ...contactRoutes
        ]
    },


];

export const routing : ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Please keep in mind you need to update URLs and names. 
Working demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/qfayHJWjqItFMWuQWfcs?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I have some confusion. My app.routing.ts is looking like   {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/myapps/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path : 'myapps/contact', component : ContactComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'myapps/home', component : HomeComponent
    }   here how may I add the child router of ContactComponent...?

Comment: just edited ,what I meant was to import another routes files into another route. so in your case please have a look at the new edit, Hope it works for you

Comment: it's really hard to understand , can you just add your codes here http://plnkr.co/ ? and send me your link (whatever you have now and it's working ) then I will fix it for you.

Comment: seems your contact.routing.ts is not importing anything. you must treat contact.routing.ts just like app.routes.ts and then export your class contactRoutes and do the rest.

Comment: Hi. Please check the link. http://plnkr.co/edit/Haexoj8ptZbKycs0pwT7. I have done it. But please ignore the links which i imported. Just check the functionalities.

Comment: It is ok.  Just tell me one thing, what should I write inside     children: [
               ...contactRoutes
           ], its just confusing.

Comment: Have a look at this file Contacts.routing.ts, basically contactRoutes is an const which has been exported and imported in the other route.